# Bootstrap 5 Modal Is Not Showing Dialog

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am completely new to Bootstrap and am trying to work it into an existing jQuery project. I can't seem to get modals to work. I have the following markup from the Bootstrap example at the bottom of my page:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="message_area">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript code is:

```
$("#message_area").modal();
```

There are no Javascript errors yet no dialog box pops up. I'm sure I'm missing something.

I stripped down my code to just include jQuery and Bootstrap JS and CSS. Using the example from Bootstrap model page, I still can't get it to work. My stripped down code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <script src="http://dev.adex-intl.com/adex/clientsSite/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.adex-intl.com/adex/clientsSite/public/js/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://dev.adex-intl.com/adex/clientsSite/public/css/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <title>Orders** DEVELOPMENT SITE **</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#message_area">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="message_area" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the DOM is fully loaded at the time your js code runs?
see https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Or put differently: is your js code inside $() or equivalent? Like $(function() { $(“#message-area”).modal(); });

Comment: I updated my question with my full HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of the difference between Bootstrap 4 and bootstrap 5:
You are stating that you use Bootstrap 5, but the toggle and target attributes you use in your button are Bootstrap 4 style.

Replace data-toggle by data-bs-toogle
and data-target by data-bs-target

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#message_area">
```

Your html page displays the modal correctly once this is fixed, as you can see [here (jsfiddle.net)](https://jsfiddle.net/pofne173/). In this example, Bootstrap and JQuery are retrieved via CDN, in order to be sure that the right code is retrieved.

Check the documentations

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/

Also, the placement of your script elements might not be optimal.
See Bootstrap recommendation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: Thank you so much! I had just done a Google search for Bootstrap modal and looked at the first one I found. I really appreciate you steering me in the right direction.